# Use TFS/ RM 2015 Environment Variables/ Custom configuration

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, ms-release-management

I have a console application that I am building on a on-premises tfs 2015 with a Visual Studio Build. What I want to achieve is:

*If the application is executed on a dev machine during normal development there will be a simple message "Hello Developer" and if it was deployed in a qa environment and the tester runs it from there it should print "Hello Tester".* Just a simple demo.

So I think I need an App.config to be able to store a configuration that will than be changed during the build process. I was confident that this is a no brainer as I found a lot of websites describing something like this but it turns out, that they all are not revealing the interesting bits like

- How does the App.config needs to look like?
- How is the variable used in C# code?
- What are the needed settings in the Release Management Client?
- What are the needed settings in the on-premises TFS Build Definition?

or were out-dated ([TFS 2013 (1)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tfssetup/archive/2015/10/15/tokenization-with-release-management.aspx), [RM Client 2013 (2)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alming/archive/2015/01/19/using-web-config-transformations-and-release-manager.aspx)) or were using [Visual Studio Online/ Team Services](https://youtu.be/SlCDrGWdy08?t=1553) or were using [custom tasks](https://github.com/TotalALM/VSTS-Tasks/tree/master/Tasks/Tokenization).

Can someone explain me, how to achieve the described scenario "Hello Developer"/ "Hello Tester"?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

We use MSDeploy for this type of setup.  You can extend MSBuild by adding an Import line in your csproj file to a new .targets file in your project.  Reference the MSDeploy task and use that to create a MSDeploy package for your console app.  Finally create Parameterization files to define the config section you want to transform and SetParameters files for each environment with the appropriate message.

[This blog post](http://dotnetcatch.com/2016/02/10/deploying-a-database-project-with-msdeploy/) is for a database project but the basics steps are the same.

Within RM you would use MSDeploy to deploy the package with the appropriate SetParmeter file against the target server via a PowerShell command.

[image]

Comment: Hi Chief, thanks for your answer and the link. But looking at the TFS2013 link mentioned above (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tfssetup/archive/2015/10/15/tokenization-with-release-management.aspx) I hope that there is a better way to realise such a console app in tfs 2015. Some things I don't like in the approach you mentioned: Hardcode path to the dll (MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll) and no real tool usage. (After Build setup is configured in the Release Management Client in the TFS2013 link, for example) Is there nothing more up to date?

Comment: The new build system is much better than 2013 in my opinion. My review -http://dotnetcatch.com/2016/01/20/review-vsts-release-management-vnext/  Although it is not currently released for TFS 2015 on-prem yet.  You can see all the capabilities in VSTS which should be coming to TFS in the coming month or two.  In general I agree hard coding dlls is a bad idea but this particular assembly is provided with VisualStudio which can be assumed will be on the build agents.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with [SlowCheetah](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/05bb50e3-c971-4613-9379-acae2cfe6f9e)?

> This package allows you to automatically transform your app.config (or
>   any file) when you press F5 in Visual Studio. You can have different
>   transformations based on the build configuration. This will enable you
>   to easily have different app settings, connection strings, etc for
>   Debug versus Release. If you want to transform other files you can do
>   that too.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I have not really tried it. Only read a little bit about it. But it doesn't seem to be the perfect fit for the release management scenario. I guess I'll try the 'Tokenizer' first: https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Release/examples/azure/change-config-azure-webapps